# How can I write the command used to invoke nohup to its log file?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, nohup

I am trying to run a command with `nohup`, for example

```
nohup python -u myscript.py --lots --of --options 1000 &> logfile.out
```

Is there any way to write the command as the first line of `logfile.out`? For example,

```
python -u myscript.py --lots --of --options 1000
Script running...
Script complete!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper function `nohup`:

```
nohup () { echo "$@"; command nohup "$@" ;}
```

Now if you do:

```
nohup python -u myscript.py --lots --of --options 1000 &> logfile.out
```

you'll get the desired command line saved along with other regular STDOUT/STDERR on `logfile.out`.

Comment: This nearly works, but it strips quotation marks from any arguments passed… eg ``python myscript.py --stringarg 'hello world'`` becomes ``python myscript.py --stringarg hello world`` in test.out…

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for this:

```
runbg() {
   out="$1"
   shift
   printf "%s\nScript Runinng...\n" "$*" > "$out"
   nohup "$@" &>> "$out" &
}
```

Then run it as:

```
runbg logfile.out python -u myscript.py --lots --of --options 1000
```